# How to show endpoints from parent project in SwaggerUI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have two projects, one is chassis-like project, with some dependencies and `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent, and one module with REST endpoint, and the second one is project with first project as parent, which has main method running Spring Boot application. 
I'm using Swagger to document this endpoint, however it doesn't show my custom endpoint from parent project. Only one endpoint I can see is `BasicErrorController` `/error`, which is also from parent Spring Boot project and I would like to show my endpoints in the same way.

I tried to annotate ExampleChassis as `@Controller` (same as in `BasicErrorController`), but it doesn't work as well (code below). Main class has annotation `@EnableSwagger2`.

Parent project `pom.xml`:

```xml
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>chassis</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <swagger2.version>2.9.2</swagger2.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>rest</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

rest module `pom.xml`:

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>chassis</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Runnable SpringBoot project `pom.xml`:

```xml
<artifactId>micro</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>chassis</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

REST endpoint:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleChassis {

    @RequestMapping
    public String getXing() {
        return "example";
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see `/example` endpoint in SwaggerUI and `.json`, but I can see only `/error` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

write your own swagger config and define a bean below, whatever base package you will provide swagger filter the API according to the same.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's only excluded /error path, but still doesn't show /example endpoint from my parent project. Also I'd created this bean in rest module, and imported it in Main class (@Import(SwaggerConfig.class), but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Also, the configuration bean is not necessary, because it takes all @ RestController and @ Controller classes. That's why SwaggerUI shows /error endpoint from BasicErrorController